# CSS override Wordpress (pinboard theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm modding a wordpress theme for my web (pinboard theme). It's an excellent theme. This theme has a build in slider/carrousel. I want to modify the title of the slider from right to left. His css style is this

```
#slider .entry-title {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:32%;
  right: none;
  z-index:1;
  float:right;
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size:36px;
  line-height:1.62em;}
```

This theme has a custom css override box so you don't have to mod the original style.css. All you have to do is insert the new css override code. I want the `right:none`gone, is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#slider .entry-title {
   left:0;
   right:auto;  
}
```